# Pipe data into shell command expecting a filename

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have a shell command `foo` that expects a file such as `bar.txt` as an argument, and I want to pass a one-line file to `foo` and then erase it like so:

```
echo "This is a one line file" > bar.txt
foo bar.txt
rm bar.txt
```

Is there a way to do this all in a single line of shell script without ever creating the file `bar.txt`?

Comment: Not without modifying `foo`. If `foo` can be modified, you could pass a string as argument or modify it to read from stdin and do: `echo long_string | foo` etc.

Comment: Some programs will read from `stdin` if you pass a dash as the filename: `foo -`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Process Substitution:

```
foo <(echo "This is a one line file")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that foo doesn't try to read stdin. If so, as an alternative to the Process Substitution suggested by Cyrus, you can also do

```
 echo "This is a one line file" | foo /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

try command substitution like this

```
cat $(ls)
```

where, result of 'ls' will be substituted as an argument for 'cat' to execute